# gapi.auth.authorize() with immediate: false doesn't popup a window for authorization

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is a javascript which simply requests authorization to access user's spreadsheets:

```
var CLIENT_ID = '********';
var SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
];
function auth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        immediate: true,
        scope: SCOPES
    }, function(result) {
        console.log('authorize(immediate = true)');
        if (result && !result.error) {
            console.log('authorize [OK]');
        } else {
            console.log('authorize [FAILED]');
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                immediate: false,
                scope: SCOPES
            }, function(result) {
                console.log('authorize(immediate = false)');
                if (result && !result.error) {
                    console.log('authorize [OK]');
                } else {
                    console.log('authorize [FAILED]');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I believe it should do two things:

1. Popup a window to login unless the user is already logged in.
2. Popup a window to request authorization to access user's spreadsheets unless the authorization had been already granted earlier. After the authorization is granted the app should be listed under [Connected apps & sites](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps) and no more popup with authorization will be shown.

I am testing this script with two distinct google accounts. One account works as expected and I get the following output on console:

```
auth.html:17 authorize(immediate = true)
auth.html:21 authorize [FAILED]
auth.html:27 authorize(immediate = false)
auth.html:29 authorize [OK]
```

With another account the popup for authorization is not shown and authorization is always granted as If I pressed "Allow" or the app was listed under *Connected apps & sites*, but it's not there. The console output is exactly the same.

I have done these tests using two browsers:

- Version 51.0.2704.79 Built on 8.4, running on Debian 8.5 (64-bit)
- Firefox ESR 45.2.0, running on Debian 8.5 (64-bit)

So, basically I have the following questions:

1. Are my expectations regarding popups correct or the idea behind the gapi.auth.authorize() call with immediate:true or immediate:false is different?
2. What can be the reason for this "misbehaving"? Is there any "sacred place" where the app is listed as authorized for some scope while the same app not shown under *Connected apps & sites*?

> Note: The CLIENT_ID is listed in **Google API Console** under *OAuth
>   2.0 client IDs*, the type is *Web application* and the owner is completely different account not related to the above mentioned two.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the app script ?

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar: Actually, I have made it simple: the problem exists without calling any App Script at all, I just call gapi.auth.authorize() to request spreadsheets permissions which will be used later by calling some App Script but that will be done after I solve the above mentioned problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. **Are my expectations regarding popups correct or the idea behind the `gapi.auth.authorize()` call with immediate:true or immediate:false is different?**

   - Yes, your expectations regarding popups are correct. As discussed in a related [issue #103](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/103) posted in GitHub, when user triggers 'gapi.auth.authorize' with button click (`immediate:false`), flow is as following:

> 1. Popup window with permissions authorization is shown
> 2. When user accept/deny, popup window is closed
> 3. instead of firing callback, TypeError appears in console (regardless of whether user authorized app to handle requested data or not)

2. **What can be the reason for this "misbehaving"? Is there any "sacred place" where the app is listed as authorized for some scope while the same app not shown under Connected apps & sites?**

   - That related [issue #103](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/103) posted in GitHub can also be the reason for this "misbehaving" and based from the thread, this has already been fixed which can be found in that [GitHub post](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

I hope that helps.